# Charging a Macbook pro 15-inch (late 2016 touch bar)

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, battery, charging

The original charger for my laptop model can output 87W. Sometimes I forget it at work and I use my Nintendo Switch Charger (Output: 15V, 2.6A = 39W) for emergencies.

I was wondering if using a charger that may not be able to input the amount of power needed (for example maybe the laptop needs 45W so it will take the rest from the battery) could damage the laptops battery?

Extra: If there is no problem, would that also hold for this power bank: [https://www.amazon.com/AUKEY-30000mAh-Portable-Delivery-Nintendo/dp/B071CQYBSN](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B071CQYBSN)

Answer (score 0):

Officially according to Apple:

> You can use a compatible higher wattage adapter without issue, but it
>   won't make your computer charge faster or operate differently. Lower
>   wattage adapters don't provide enough power.

There is no mention of risking damage to the battery, but you may not be able to charge at all at lower wattages.

Additionally, you have to use a USB-C cable that is meant for charging. The Switch cable appears to be made for such.

In personal experience with MagSafe-powered MacBook Pros, the battery indicator in the menu may say "Battery is not charging", but I've noticed it stays powered on longer than just running off the internal battery alone. Your miles may vary.

Source: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201700